# LaTeXで大型演算子の\wedgeを用いた数式を組みたい

Tags: latex

期待する出力は写真の「ココ」の箇所です。
私は以下のようにプログラムしましたが、期待した出力結果となりませんでした。
どこをどのように修正すればいいのでしょうか。

[image: 再現したい組版結果の画像]

```
\textbf{7.5　閉検定手順}

7.1説で考察した母平均が0でない多重比較検定するときの帰無仮説のファミリーは
[
\mathcal{D}{0}≡{H{0i}|1≦i≦k}
]
である。$\mathcal{L}{0}≡{i|1≦i≦k}に対して、に対して、\mathcal{D}{0}の要素の仮説の要素の仮説H_{0i}$の論理積からなるすべての集合は
\begin{displaymath}
\displaystyle\mathcal{\bar{D}}{0}≡\left{\land{i∈E}{H_{0i}}\varsubsetneqq{E}\subset\mathcal{L}_{0}\right}
\end{displaymath}
```

Answer (score 3):

こんな感じでいかがでしょう。

```tex
\documentclass{jlreq}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[
\mathcal{\overline{D}}_{0}\equiv\left\{\bigwedge_{i\in E}H_{0i}\mathrel{}\middle|\mathrel{}\varnothing\subsetneqq E\subset\mathcal{I}_{0}\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]